# Is there a better way to calculate the values in a Map?

Tags: java, data-structures, treemap

I just finished the main part of the current data structures project, and am working on collecting the statistics.  One requirement is that a count of all the references within the TreeMap be recorded.

This Map contains a 31,000+ nodes where a String is mapped to a TreeSet of indeterminate size.
I need to traverse the map and keep a running count of the number of items in the set.

Originally my idea was this:

```
Set<String> keySet= lyricWords.keySet();  
Iterator<String> iter= keySet.iterator();
String current= iter.next();

while (iter.hasNext){
  runCount+= lyricWords.get(current).size();
}
```

The runtime for this is far too long to be acceptable.  Is there a more efficient way to do this on the final structure?  I could keep a count as the map is built, but the professor wants the numbers to be based on the final structure itself.

Comment: inside the while loop you ought to have iter = iter.next()

Comment: Side note: Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java* recommends using the for each syntax ( `for  (String s : lyricWords.keySet())` ) rather than directly using iterators in Java 5 and newer if possible. (p 212)

Comment: @Mikhail: actually, he ought to use the enhanced for loop. Iterators are so last millenium...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't of much use to you since this is an assignment you're working on, but this is an example where a data structure specifically designed for mapping keys to multiple values shows how much better it is than a `Map<T, Collection<V>>`.

[Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com)'s `Multimap` collection type keeps track of the total number of entries it contains, so if you were using a `TreeMultimap<String, Foo>` rather than a `TreeMap<String, TreeSet<Foo>>` you could just call `multimap.size()` to get the number you're looking for.

By the way, the `Multimap` implementations store a running total of the number of entries which is updated when entries are added to or removed from it. You *might* be able to do this by doing some fancy stuff with subclassing the `TreeMap` and wrapping the `TreeSet`s that are added to it, but it would be quite challenging to make it all work properly I think.

Comment: THanks for the lead.  Even though I won't use it in this project, I accepted your answer since you did give me the best response to my question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure. But, probably, you have infinitive loop. Try:

```
runCount+= iter.next().size();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, TreeSet> e: lyricWords.entrySet()) {
  runCount+= e.getValue().size();
}
```

Comment: Definitely prefer this way of doing it.

Comment: Agreed, but how is it more efficient than the original solution? (Perhaps only for the lack of an infinite loop) ... doing it the way thejh suggest spares you the infinite loop, but in these kinds of projects you should learn to do it with an iterator, for the very reason that you need to recognize when an infinite loop might occur and how to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont see a problem with keeping a count as the map is built.

The count will be correct at the end, and you wont have to incur the cost of iterating through the entire thing again.

I think that the tree can and *should* keep track of its size

Comment: This would be rather difficult unless the whole process of building the map is being done in one place. How would the total be updated if one of the TreeSets that had been added to the map had something added to it later elsewhere?

Comment: for some reason i assumed that he has a class that contains the maps and the trees and he is accessing the maps through this.